# jQuery autocomplete breaks in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, autocomplete

I have several jQuery autocomplete searches set up like this one. They all work as expected in safari, chrome and opera but not in firefox.

Any ideas what could make firefox choke, have i used deprecated code? the jQuery ui example looks more simple but its not ajax and this method below is the way i could get it to work.

Would appreciate a pointer as to why it doesnt work in firefox.

```
$('#typeCode').autocomplete({
    appendTo: "#typeLeft",
    source: 'maType/typeSearch.php',
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
//alert( "You selected: "+ui.item.museum_city);
        var $itemrow = $(this).closest('tr');
        $itemrow.find('#typeCode').val(ui.item.content+ " "+ ui.item.museum_city + " " + ui.item.museum_state_name);

    $.ajax({
        url: "maType/typeSearchByName.php?Type="+ui.item.content+"&City="+ ui.item.museum_city +"&StateName="+ ui.item.museum_state_name+"",
        cache: true,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#typeRight').fadeOut('100', function(){
            $(this).html(data).fadeIn('250')
            });
        } // success
    }); // ajax

 // Give focus to the next input field to recieve input from user
                $('#itemQty').focus();

        return false;
    }


// Format the list menu output of the autocomplete
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.content + " "+ item.museum_city + " " + item.museum_state_name +"</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying dataType: 'text' as a property to the $.ajax call

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it did not help. I am not that handy with the firefox console so did not notice that the jvectormaps broke in firefox and because the jvectormap links were before the autocomplete links, they also broke the autocomplete links.  I have added [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833621/jvectormaps-in-dropdown-menu-ns-error-failure] (another question on the jvectormaps problem) in stack overflow because i can't work out how to fix the jvectormap problem.  In the meantime i moved the jvectormap links after the autocomplete ones. a dirty hack.