# AngularJS delay compiling directive until element is visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fancybox-2, jvectormap

I have an angular directive that renders a [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/).

When the page first loads, the map is hidden, but the user can click on a link to show the map in a [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

It's working perfectly fine in Chrome and IE, but Firefox yells at me when rendering SVG on a hidden element (i get `NS_ERROR_FAILURE`) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31840099/1706504))

So based on that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31840099/1706504), I'm trying to get my map directive to not render/compile until it's visible, which I think will fix the issue in Firefox.

Is there a way to do this, or am I going about this in the wrong way?

THANKS!!

**Update**

Using `ng-if` *does* work, however in [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/) the user can select regions and markers on the map.  I'd like for those selections to persist even after the fancyBox is closed. `ng-if` removes the map all together.

**directive**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive("selectionMap", electionMap);

    function selectionMap(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            link : function(scope,element){
                jVectorMapOptions = {
                    // set jvm options (http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/)
                    option : 'something',
                    option2: 'something else'
                    // and so on 
                };
            element.vectorMap(jVectorMapOptions);

            }
        }
    }
```

How I use the directive in **html**:

```
<div id="mapModal" ng-show="mapSelected">
    <selection-map id="myMap"></selection-map>
</div>
```

The `mapModal` div shows inside a fancybox-2 modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead of ng-show.  This will create the HTML elements on the page when the condition is satisfied, and remove them when it's not.

Comment: Thanks @Mator this _does_ work, however in `jvectormap` the user has the ability to select markers and regions on the map.  When closing the fancybox, I'd like for the map selections to persist when opening up the fancybox map again. `ng-if` will remove the map entirely once the fancybox is closed. Will modify my question to be more clear

Comment: Yes, that is a drawback of using `ng-if`.  The obvious (but most likely overly difficult) approach would be to store the user's selections and then re-apply them when the jvectormap is recreated.

As an alternative to this you could look into hiding the map by some custom directive which would set its height to 0 or using z-index to put it behind your page (this would be very hacky).

Comment: I took your approach and all is working fine. Thanks!